# Weak and Weak$^{\star}$ topologies: Annihilator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

**Exercise:**

Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $M\subset E$ be a linear subspace and let $f_0\in E^{\star}$. Prove that there exists some $g_0\in M^{\perp}$ s.t.
\begin{equation}\inf_{g\in M^{\perp}}\Vert f_0-g \Vert=\Vert f_0-g_0\Vert \end{equation}
where $M^{\perp}:=\{ f\in E^{\star}: <f,x>=0 ~\forall x\in M \}$ is the annihilator of M.

**Solution:**

We use the fact that the unit ball in $E^{\star}$ is weak$^{\star}$ compact together with the fact that $M^{\perp}$ is weak$^{\star}$ closed.

**My question:** How can we conclude? Why are those two facts enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r := \inf_{g \in M^\perp} \Vert f_0 - g \Vert$. For any $g_0 \in M^\perp$ we have: $\frac{r}{\Vert f_0 - g_0 \Vert} \leq 1$, by definition of the infimum. Pick a sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Vert f_0 - g_n \Vert = r$. Since the unit-ball in $E^\ast$ is compact $(f_0 - g_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence $(f_0 - g_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbf{N}}$ in $E^\ast$. Let $g_0 := f_0 - \left( \lim_{k \to \infty} f_0 - g_{n_k} \right)$. Then since $M^\perp$ is closed, we have $g_0 \in M^\perp$.